# SoftEther VPN Server returning error. "Error occurred. (Error code: 1) Connection to the server failed. Check network connection ...."

Tags: server, vpn, firewall, localhost

This topic had already been discussed in [SoftEther VPN Server can't connect during set up.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/595387/softether-vpn-server-cant-connect-during-set-up)

But cannot find the solution here in my case. Tried commenting still not received a resolution. So please answer to any of these threads.

As it had been answered in the above Question, tried providing the `localhost:5555` as well as `127.0.0.1:5555`
Still it is throwing error.

```
*Error occurred. (Error code: 1)
Connection to the server failed. Check network connection and make sure that address and port number of destination server are correct.*
```

Localhost is pinging and firewall is inactive.

**ufw status**

```
Status: inactive
```

Kindly help it.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your VPN is running:

> **sudo ./vpnclient start**

It's very critical!
Thank you

Comment: hi..thanks... i will giveit a check and get back to you

Comment: You know, after some research, I couldn't get softether to work, even after completing all steps, it shows that it works but actually not. So I found another way OpenConnect Server, give him a try, it's also compatible with ANY OS (OsX, Linux, Win, WinPhone, Android, IOS)